# How to create a short name for tramp multihop path?

Tags: tramp, aliases

I connect to various locations, for example:

```
/ssh:hostname|sudo:hostname:/
/ssh:hostname|sudo:hostname|docker:container:/
```

and want to have some kind of short aliases for these long paths.
Something like this:

```
/su-hn:/
/dk-hn:/
```

How can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use environment variables for the tramp paths.

For an example you could add the following line to your init file (with the right substitution for `hostname`):

```
(setenv "suHn" "/ssh:hostname|sudo:hostname:")
```

Those variables are resolved if you use them like `$suHn/` at the prompt of `find-file`.

Note however that I am not sure about the pipe-character `|` in your tramp path. I never used such syntax for tramp and it is also not mentioned in [tramp's file name conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/File-name-syntax.html).

Comment: Thank you, it is the most useful approach at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Read the Tramp Manual, chapter Frequently Asked Questions (https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Frequently-Asked-Questions). It explains in length several approaches to shorten remote file names. These approaches are valid also for multi-hop file names.